# jslint Missing property name

Tags: jslint

I am using jslint. I have this tolerance setting in my comments.

```
/*jslint todo: true*/
```

The online tester passes it. I have it passing in a piece of code tested earlier. However, later on I get this failure message:

```
Missing property name.
```

Does anyone know why the property name is regarded as missing in the second place and not the first?

**Update 17/072014 15:03 - included code**

I was able to isolate the issue with the following code. Below you can see the parts of the code if run in [lint.com](http://www.jslint.com/) and what errors they output:

```
/**
  * @todo "Unexpected TODO comment".
  */

/*jslint todo: true*/
/**
  * @todo Will be tolerated by jslint.
  */
/*jslint todo: false*/

var obj = {
    /**
      * @todo "Unexpected TODO comment".
      */
};

/*jslint todo: true*/
var obj = {
    /**
      * @todo jslint will tolerate this line.
      */
};
/*jslint todo: false*/

var obj = {
    /*jslint todo: true*/
    /**
      * @todo jslint will never get to this line.
      */
    /*jslint todo: false*/
};
```

What I found was that the tolerance properties could not be set inside an object literal. I can now work around the issue.

I had trouble finding documentation on the issue because my searches for 'literal' were being obscured by the literal notation errors. Does anyone know why this occurs or if there is documentation to explain it, or even just state that it happens?

Comment: I've now included the code and some additional information.

Answer (score 2):

JSLint does not like it when you introduce `/* */` comments inside of objects.

For example, I had this error with this code:

```
config.output = {
    /*jslint nomen:true*/
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    /*jslint nomen:false*/

    publicPath: BUILD ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: BUILD ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: BUILD ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].bundle.js'
};
```

And it was resolved by changing that to:

```
/*jslint nomen:true*/
config.output = {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    publicPath: BUILD ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: BUILD ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: BUILD ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].bundle.js'
};
/*jslint nomen:false*/
```

I know it's been a year or two since you asked but, hopefully this helps anyone else who is looking.